# Routing independant controllers and models in fat free framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, navigation, fat-free-framework

I am trying to create Main site navigation, Sidebar Navigation and Footer navigation in Fat Free environment. I am just starting to work with frameworks especially with MVC type.

My problem, since my navigation will be almost on every page of the website, I was thinking about creating separate controller and model to handle all this staff, but not sure how it would work without making routing?

Also, I am not sure how to handle join in the model, I could not find any information about this online at all.

Here is my current Category Controller

```
class Categories extends DB\SQL\Mapper
{
    public function __construct(DB\SQL $db)
    {
        parent::__construct($db, 'categories');
    }

    public function all()
    {
        $this->load();
        return $this->query;
    }

    public function getByID($id)
    {
        $this->load(array('id=?', $id));
        return $this->query;
    }

    public function getBySlug($category_slug)
    {
        $this->load(array('category_slug=?', $category_slug));
        return $this->query;
    }

    public function add()
    {
        $this->copyfrom('POST');
        $this->save();
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $this->load(array('id=?', $id));
        $this->copyfrom('POST');
        $this->update();
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->load(array('id=?', $id));
        $this->erase();
    }
}
```

any ideas or pointers will help me to go a long way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like a model. Not a controller.

Comment: It is a Model, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if understood what your issue is, but if you want to make the categories available for all methods in a Controller, you could use the `beforeRoute()` method:

```
class TestController extends MainController {

    // runs before routing
    // if another controller extends TestController and also has a 
    // beforeRoute, this will be overriden
    function beforeRoute() {

        // Load Categories
        $categories = new Categories($this->db);
        // Assiging ->all() to variable makes the method return an array of all results
        $categoriesArray = $categories->all();
        // Set an array in the hive for template use 
        $this->f3->set('categories', $categoriesArray );
        // Clear the instance
        $categories->reset();

    }

    function renderPage() {

        // the 'categories' hive variable is available because beforeRoute has been run 


        // Set the page title from the dictionary file
        $this->f3->set('pageTitle', $this->f3->get('DICT_'.'page_whatever') );
        // Render the View
        $this->f3->set('view','page.whatever.htm');
        $template=\Template::instance();
        echo $template->render('layout.sidebar.htm');

    }

// End of Controller
}
```

And of course, in the template:

```
<repeat group="@categories" value="@category">
  <li>
    <a href="{{ @category.uri }}">{{ @category.label }}</a>
  </li>
</repeat>
```

ps: You might be using `$f3` instead of `$this->f3` (and the same for `$db`)